# How to plot two density curves of two continuous variables on the same chart

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm new to R so I hope that my question is not too simple.I'm trying to plot two density curves of two continuous variables: LTV1 and LTV2 - on the same plot.
Doing each density was simple, I used ggplot2 with this lines of code:
`qplot(LTV1, data = dat, geom = "density", main="LTV1")` and
`qplot(LTV2, data = dat, geom = "density", main="LTV2")`
But I didn't find a way to put them on the same plot.Any Idea how can It be done?
Here is my data frame example:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " UserID LTV1 LTV2 
                   123        3        9      
                   654        3        8         
                   658        1        2         
                   333        1        2         
                   455        1        8         
                   857        6        1         
                   542        6        7         
                   785        6        1         
                   357        5        9         
                   963        8        5 
                   444        2        1
                   524        2        2 
                   777        6        2 
                   564        1        1 
                   786        3        9 
                   412        1        4   ",header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ggplot` perfers it's data in tall format rather than a wide format such as how you have it. The easiest way to convert between the two is with the `reshape2` pacakge. In this case, we need the `melt()` function. How about

```
ggplot(melt(dat, "UserID"), aes(value, color=variable)) + geom_density() + xlim(-5,15)
```

[image]

Note that we had to manually extend the `xlim` to get the density to go down to 0. The default is to just zoom into the region where you have observations.

Alternative you could add multiple density layers

```
ggplot(dat) + 
   geom_density(aes(LTV1, color="LTV1")) + 
   geom_density(aes(LTV2, color="LTV2")) + 
   scale_color_hue(name="Variable")
```

[image]

however this would not scale very well if you had a bunch of columns. It's usually easier to just reshape your data